# Building Unity with Jenkins - Platform directives not defined?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jenkins

I am trying to build my Unity project with Jenkins.

Created a BuildScript with the following calls (not all is shown):

```
BuildPlayerOptions options = new BuildPlayerOptions();
options.scenes = new string[] { "Assets/game.unity" };
options.targetGroup = BuildTargetGroup.Android;
options.target = BuildTarget.Android;
options.locationPathName = "/Users/Admin/my.apk";

BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(options);
```

When I call this build from a **local shell**, the build works great and an apk is created.

When I try to call it from Jenkins using the Unity3d plugin, I get a strange compilation error which seems to be related to a missing **UNITY_ANDROID** directive. So basically code inside

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
...
#endif
```

Is not called.

Is there any reason why when my code is compiled from the Jenkins build, the above directive (and others I guess) are not defined automatically?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this one, by trial and error.

It appears that when I ran the build with a **-projectPath**, Unity does not recognise the platform and set the directive.

Adding the **-buildTarget Android** command line to the build, solves this issue.